# CSS first List item an image the rest red dots

Tags: html, css

How to I create a CSS for a list, where the first item is an image (centered) and the rest should be a red dot.

I dont want to work with

```
<p></p>
```

or somthing.

This is my code:

```
<style>
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin :0;
    padding:;
}

li:first-child{
    background:url('http://imi.shirtcity.com/gfx/icons/16x16/icon_heart_active.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
li:before{
   content: "• ";
   color: red;
}

</style>
<ul>
    <li>Nulla facilisi.</li>
    <li>Pellentesque habitant morbi</li>
    <li>Quisque vel justo.</li>
    <li>Nullam posuere purus sed arcu.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `after` or `before` in this case. you can use `list-style: disc` and for background use `list-style-image`

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin :0;
    padding:;
}

li {
  list-style: disc;
  color: red;
}

li a {
  color: black;
}

li:first-child{
    list-style-image: url('http://imi.shirtcity.com/gfx/icons/16x16/icon_heart_active.png');
    line-height: px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Nulla facilisi.</a></li>
    <li><a>Pellentesque habitant morbi</a></li>
    <li><a>Quisque vel justo.</a></li>
    <li><a>Nullam posuere purus sed arcu.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin :0;
    padding:;
}

ul li:first-child{
    background:url('http://imi.shirtcity.com/gfx/icons/16x16/icon_heart_active.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style-type:none!important;
}

li:not(:first-child):before{
   content: "• ";
   color: red;
}
```

You'll see that I added a `:not` selector for the red dot, this excludes the fist child.

Secondly I've added the `ul` to get the heart to work.

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ho3s0u4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sequence of css definition and add `:before` also to your `:first-child` definition resetting the `content`

```
<style>
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin :0;
    padding:;
}
li:before{
   content: "• ";
   color: red;
}
li:first-child:before{
    content: "";
    background:url('http://imi.shirtcity.com/gfx/icons/16x16/icon_heart_active.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>
```